# Unexpected result from Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

Tags: python, scipy.stats

I have this code to check the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. But it gives the wrong result. What is the problem?

```
import pandas
import random

import matplotlib
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
datas = [0.3877, 0.3878, 0.3877, 0.3877, 0.3877, 0.3879, 0.3899, 0.3892, 0.3881, 0.3873, 0.3886, 0.3875, 0.3876, 0.3893, 0.3888, 0.3886, 0.388, 0.3886, 0.387, 0.3872, 0.388, 0.3877, 0.3867, 0.3898, 0.3878, 0.3886, 0.3883, 0.388, 0.3877, 0.3886, 0.3877, 0.3879, 0.3883, 0.3878, 0.3882, 0.3878, 0.3883, 0.3867, 0.3881, 0.3883, 0.3882, 0.3884, 0.3876, 0.3878, 0.3886, 0.3885, 0.3865, 0.3874, 0.3878, 0.388]
from scipy.stats import kstest

print(kstest(datas, 'norm'))
```

Must be

```
KstestResult(statistic=0.11781653619879678, pvalue=0.45678095532064167
```

According to my data, this is coming out:

```
KstestResult(statistic=0.6504367986973135, pvalue=3.3658717487529006e-21
```

Comment: What do all those other imports have to do with this question? You're not plotting anything, you don't use numpy, random, or pandas.

Comment: Yes, it’s redundant, you’re right.. This refers to another piece of code that works

Comment: I doubt that the code in scipy is wrong. Why do you think your result is correct?

Comment: There are two different questions here: 1) How well does this data fit a normal distribution? and 2) How well does this data fit a normal distribution with mu=0 and sigma=1? Scipy is answering question #2, but I suspect you really want question #1. Is that right?

Comment: e.g. if I subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation of `datas`, I get this result: `KstestResult(statistic=0.11610318522195917, pvalue=0.4752759129992553)` which is closer to what you expected.

Comment: @NickODell Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: @DaniK `from scipy.stats import zscore; datas = zscore(datas)`

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.stats.kstest` appears to be producing the correct statistic and an appropriate p-value here. Evidence includes agreement with R:

```
options(digits=16)
x = c(0.3877, 0.3878, 0.3877, 0.3877, 0.3877, 0.3879, 0.3899, 0.3892, 0.3881, 0.3873, 0.3886, 0.3875, 0.3876, 0.3893, 0.3888, 0.3886, 0.388, 0.3886, 0.387, 0.3872, 0.388, 0.3877, 0.3867, 0.3898, 0.3878, 0.3886, 0.3883, 0.388, 0.3877, 0.3886, 0.3877, 0.3879, 0.3883, 0.3878, 0.3882, 0.3878, 0.3883, 0.3867, 0.3881, 0.3883, 0.3882, 0.3884, 0.3876, 0.3878, 0.3886, 0.3885, 0.3865, 0.3874, 0.3878, 0.388)
ks.test(x, 'pnorm')  # D = 0.65043679869731, p-value < 2.2204460493e-16
```

and Matlab

```
x = [0.3877, 0.3878, 0.3877, 0.3877, 0.3877, 0.3879, 0.3899, 0.3892, 0.3881, 0.3873, 0.3886, 0.3875, 0.3876, 0.3893, 0.3888, 0.3886, 0.388, 0.3886, 0.387, 0.3872, 0.388, 0.3877, 0.3867, 0.3898, 0.3878, 0.3886, 0.3883, 0.388, 0.3877, 0.3886, 0.3877, 0.3879, 0.3883, 0.3878, 0.3882, 0.3878, 0.3883, 0.3867, 0.3881, 0.3883, 0.3882, 0.3884, 0.3876, 0.3878, 0.3886, 0.3885, 0.3865, 0.3874, 0.3878, 0.388]
[h,p,ksstat,cv]  = kstest(x)
% ksstat = 0.6504
% p = 1.7292e-19
```

As an aside, note that there are ties in the data, but the null distribution of the test statistic is derived under the assumption that the underlying distribution is continuous (no ties).